# Angular 5 route issue

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have following routes in my application.

```
const flowRoutes: Routes  = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'landingpage', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'landingpage', component: LandingPageComponent },
{ path: 'limitexcession/dashboard?Primary=true', component: LimitExcessionDashboardComponent },
{ path: 'limitexcession/:excessionID', component: LimitExcessionComponent },
```

];

limitexcession/dashboard?Primary=true and limitexcession/:excessionID are different routes. But both components are getting initialized if I route to limitexcession/dashboard?Primary=true. 
But if I removed primary=true from the route it's not getting initialised.

Can any one help ?

Comment: Why do you want to include query params in your route's path? What is the expected outcome of that?

Comment: I have enabled some default filter using that query params

Comment: Ok, but that shouldn't be sepcified in the path of your route but in your default redirect. I don't beleive angular router parses query parameters. Therefore your route never gets activated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is following query  parameter ?Primary=true.
Pls reference below url: https://angular-xbj5n8.stackblitz.io

It is working fine if we remove hard-coded queryparam

Comment: Thanks. That I know. But I want to use that query params.

Comment: I am suggesting to use the following approach: 1. this.router.navigate(['page1/something'], { queryParams: { Primary: 'true' }   2. <a [routerLink]="['page1/something']" [queryParams]="{Primary: 'true'}">Page1</a>